# wamp MSSQL php Extension not showing up

Tags: php

I setup Wamp Correctly, icon is green. I got php 5.4.0 setup. I downloaded the microsoft 3.0 php mssql drivers, dragged them to the php ext folder.

In the phpforapache.ini file I added in the comments:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll
```

Now when I go to the the localhost phpinfo() sqlsrv is not there.

Comment: And yes I did restart all services on wamp and quite and started again but problem still exists.

Comment: There are 2 or 3 places with WAMP where php.ini files exist, you'll probably have to update at least one more, e.g. in `wamp\bin\apache\apachex.x.xx\bin\php.ini`

Comment: yeah the comments are there also but it is still not showing up.